# Firefox says it's up to date while it is NOT

Tags: firefox, portable-apps

I'm running Firefox on my computer, a 32 bits portable edition from portableapps.com.

When I click on `Help` > `About Firefox...`

[image: About]

The popup informs me that `Firefox is up to date.`

While, in fact, it is not.

[image: MyBrowser]

What's happening here?

Comment: I guess you have to use their platform to have access to their "Automatic Software Updates" feature.

Comment: I'd guess that the portable package has automatic updates blocked. It uses their custom launcher to "portabilize" Firefox and it would most likely not play nice with automatic updates.

Comment: I do not desire automatic updates. I've always update manually without any problem. I can update manually now if I decide to.

Comment: Today suddenly the about popup informs me that Firefox 52.0.2 was available... I updated, whitout the need of the PortableApps.com app launcher or a fresh install. Still I don't know what happened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PortableApps.com disables automatic update to prevent Firefox from updating itself. (It is said in their fine-print.) You need to use the PortableApps.com app launcher to update your Firefox. Or... by downloading and installing a fresh package from PortableApps.com. (That's what the app launcher do anyway. No delta downloading or such bandwidth-saving tricks.)

That said, you might want to check a few things around your Firefox configurations:

1. Open a new tab
2. Navigate to `about:config`
3. Access the search bar and search for `app.update.`
4. Make sure the following parameters are all set to their defaults. If not, you can right-click on them and select "Reset".

   1. `app.update.enabled`
   2. `app.update.url`
   3. `app.update.channel`
5. Make sure the following parameters are set to "false"

   1. `app.update.auto`
   2. `app.update.silent`

Now, restart your Firefox and try again, i.e. go to "About..." dialog box and see if Firefox notices the presence of a new update. **But don't update from there.** Like I said you need to use the PortableApps.com app launcher to update your Firefox. Or... by downloading and installing a fresh package from PortableApps.com.

Comment: Maybe it’s said in their fine print, but it isn’t true. My portable FF updated to version 52 today. It asked first, so it’s not entirely automatic. But I certainly didn’t download anything.

Comment: @DanielB Because you can re-enable it by going to about:config or options. Anyway, they disabled it for a reason: If you update Firefox using its built-in updater, only the version you are running gets updated. But in reality, Firefox Portable comes with both 32-bit and 64-bit Firefox. So, if you, for instance, move from the 64-bit computer you always worked with, to a 32-bit computer, you'll notice an outdated Firefox Portable.

Comment: `app.update.auto` is `false`. It will still offer updates and opening the “About” window will properly check for them.

Comment: @DanielB Again, not really surprising. Since there are three update states, not two, a simple binary choice is not enough. There must be another config key. (The three update states are automatic update, automatic check, totally manual.) You said it asked you. Hence, yours is on automatic check. I am seeing an `app.update.enabled` already.

Comment: Yes, of course. And, believe it or not, it’s enabled by default on Portable Firefox. I created a new installation to check.

Comment: I've checked your list, reset all entries starting by `app.update`to default. Going to about...I see the wheel, Firefox is checking and still says 51.0.1 is up to date...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when your internet provider blocks the Firefox-related websites, it can show as "Firefox is up to date", as it cannot connect to check for updates in the first place.

Make sure you have a connection to the website by first checking it in your browser. Then try again! You can also use a VPN service to change your country and then check for updates.

This WILL work although it seems ridiculous. Telling you based on my own experience.

Comment: Why would my provider blocks Firefox-related websites ?!? 
My connection is working.

Comment: Well, mine does and it's the only thing I can think of. Please try a VPN service and then check for Firefox updates. Sorry took so long to answer.